# The restricted product topology of locally compact spaces is locally compact

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that the restricted product topology of lcoally compact spaces is locally compact. Let $X_i$ locally compact topological spaces, and $K_i$ corresponding compact open subsets. I consider the restricted product $X$ of the $X_i$ with respect to the $K_i$.

The basis of neighborhood for the restricted product is given by open sets of the form
$$\prod_{i \in S} U_i \times \prod_{i \notin S} K_i$$
where $S$ is a finite set, and $U_i$ is open in $X_i$. We can as usual consider the $S$-restricted product
$$X_S = \prod_{i\in S} X_i \prod_{i\notin S} K_i.$$
It is clear that the $X_S$ cover $X$, and I would like to this to prove the local compactness of $X$. Let $x \in X$, this $x \in X_S$ for a certain $S$. Since $X_S$ is locally compact (essentially a finite product), $x$ has a compact open neighborhood $U$ in $X_S$.

I would like to prove (or disprove?) that $U$ is a compact open in $X$. I can see that an open cover of $U$ in $X$ restricts to an open cover of $U$ in $X_S$, thus there is a finite subcover. But what ensures that this subcover also works in $X$, i.e. that $U$ is covered in $X$ by it?

Comment: The product of locally compact spaces need not be compact, see the right result in my answer. E.g. $\Bbb R^I$ is not locally compact for infinite $I$.

Comment: Also, a locally compact space need not have open compact subsets. It has a compact *neighbourhood* for every point, where a neighbourhood need not be open, but contains an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but the result to go for is this:

> If $X_i$, $i \in S$ is a collection of non-empty spaces then $X=\prod_{i \in S} X_i$ is locally compact iff all $X_i, i \in S$ are locally compact and there is a finite $F \subseteq S$ such that $X_i$ is compact for all $i \in S\setminus F$.

The left to right implication seems your concern here. If for *some* $p=(x_i)_{i \in S}$ has *a* compact neighbourhood $K$ in $X$ it contains a basic open neighbourhood that only depends on finite many coordinates $F$ and then it follows that, as $X_i = \pi_i[K]$ for $i \notin F$, that all those $X_i$ are compact. The rest is routine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for rephrasing the setting. I am in fact more interested in the right to left implication. Indeed, take a neighborhood $K$ of $x$ that is compact in $X_S$ (if $x\in X_S$). This is possible since we are dealing with a finite product, therefore also locally compact. What ensures that this $K$ (embedded in $X$) is also a compact neighborhood of $x$ (viewed in $X$)? I was trying to justify this looking at open covers of $K$ in $X$, and using what we know about open covers in $X_S$ (see 22.6 https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes22.pdf, but I don't get it)

Comment: @Wolker compactness is absolute.

Comment: If the right hand condition holds, and $x \in X$ we pick a compact neighbourhood $C_i$ for $x_i$ when $i \in F$ and define $U=\prod_{i \notin F} X_i \times \prod_{i \in F} C_i$, which is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, and a neighbourhood of $x$ by the definition of the product topology. So $X$ is locally compact. @Wolker